# How to return the JSON with present as false in a REST API implemented with Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cities")
public class CityController {
    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @GetMapping("/{cityId}")
    public Optional<City> readCity(@PathVariable Integer cityId) {
        return cityRepository.findById(cityId);
    }
}
```

I once was able be return an error message in JSON format by default when giving a nonexisting `cityId`:

```
{
    "present": false
}
```

But when I tried to reproduce by giving a nonexisting `cityId`, I got the `null` result in the response body.

My relevant dependencies in `pom.xml` are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.data.rest.webmvc.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

**Question: I would like to reproduce the previous response as `{"present": false}, which is probably the default JSON in Spring in case of no resource found, how to get that?`**

Comment: What does the City class consist of?

Comment: The `City` class consists of coutry and city name, which is nothing related to the `{"present":false}`

Comment: And what has changed within your code since you're not getting the present field as response?

Comment: @MadhuBhat I actually don't remember the changes I made. But with current configuration in the `CityController` class, I cannot get the ``{"present": false} anyway :<

Comment: The issue is with the serialization of the Optional object. Have you used an objectMapper class anywhere?Can you please add your pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: Can you please tell what response is returned when you return Optional.empty() instead of cityRepository.findById(cityId) in the method?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve it: custom `HttpMessageConverters`, custom `JsonSerializer` if using Jackson.

In your case, I would return a `ResponseEntity` like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cities")
public class CityController {
    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @GetMapping("/{cityId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> readCity(@PathVariable Integer cityId) {
        return cityRepository.findById(cityId)
                   .map(ResponseEntity::<Object>ok)
                   .orElse(ResponseEntity.ok(Collections.singletonMap("present", false)));
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I don't like returning a response like `{"present": false}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not I would like to know. What I mean is that the result `{"present":false}` is returned by default without hard-code like `Collections.singletonMap("present", false)`

Comment: What do you mean by "resource found"? If you want a simple way to return `{"present": false}` whenever you want, I would throw a custom exception `ResourceNotFoundException` and use a handler to translate the exception to that response.